# foreach two arrays with str_replace

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, str-replace

Lets say I have two arrays got from pre_gmatch:

```
preg_match_all('#<div class="cloud_flow_big">(.*?)</div>#is', $mystring, $names, PREG_SET_ORDER);
preg_match_all('#<div class="bgframe(.*?)</div></div>#is', $mystring, $numbers, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Items count in gotten arrays is always the same. So here is the code to get what is going on, and there is one repetitive word in all items of first array (this word is **number** in this case):

```
foreach ($names as $key => $name) {
    $i++;
$nameclean = str_replace ("number", $numbers[$key], $names[$key]);
echo $nameclean;
}
```

So how to foreach first array, but in result to replace needed word in 1st array with the needed item from array 2. Example: Word **number** in 1st item from array $names should be replaced with first item from array $numbers (**First**)

Comment: I've edited the code to better describe the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, here I fixed it for you:

```
<?PHP

$names = array('John is number', 'Tom is number', 'Ben is number', 'Tony is number', 'Peter is number');
$numbers = array('First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth', 'Fifth');

foreach ($names as $key => $name) {
    $nameclean = str_replace ("number", $numbers[$key], $names[$key]);
    echo $nameclean . "<br />";

}

?>
```

Your error was in the str_replace(). You were making the replacement in the array $name[$key] which is only the name itself. You want to make the replacements from the $names[$key] array value.

Answer (score 0):

the subject(3rd parameter of `str_replace`) must be either `$names[$key]` or `$name`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
    foreach ($names as $key => &$item) {
        $item = str_replace ("number", $numbers[$key], $item);
    }
```